# Is "arguments" an invalid parameter name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is "arguments" an invalid parameter name in JavaScript?

I ask because I experienced a problem with this in PhantomJS.

Comment: It's an additional implicit argument, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: "I experienced a problem with this in PhantomJs". What was the code snippet that caused the problem? What error message did you receive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use it as an identifier (function argument, variable, etc.) *in strict mode*; [details](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-early-errors). In loose mode, you're allowed to use it. This is to avoid conflicts with the [`arguments` pseudo-array](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arguments-exotic-objects) that all non-arrow functions have. (It isn't technically a [reserved word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words), but you won't go far wrong pretending it is.)

Gratuitous live examples:

Works in loose mode:

```js
// Works in loose mode
function foo(arguments) {
  console.log("arguments is " + arguments);
}
foo(42);
```

...and not in strict mode:

```js
"use strict";
// And not in strict mode
function foo(arguments) {
  console.log("arguments is " + arguments);
}
foo(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a special object corresponding to the arguments that got passed to a function. So unless you're using it for that purpose, it could potentially give you problems.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: `function foo(arguments) { console.log(arguments); }` works just fine in general... "Yes it is" is a bit too emphatic.

Answer (score -2):

It's one of many reserved words.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Edit: Okay, T.J., it's not, BUT was not entirely wrong. According to David Flanagan in Javascript, The Definitive Guide, 'arguments' is forbidden as a name for parameters, variables or functions when being in strict mode.

Comment: [No, it isn't](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words). Yet Another Reason not to rely on w3schools. *(not my dv)*

Comment: From that site: *"JavaScript is often used together with Java."* – WTF W3S?!

Comment: Entirely plausible. Others use JavaScript together with C#. I do. My server components are .net MVC Web API. There's a life beyond node.js.